# ItemsControl Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate that is bound to an ObservableCollection of integers.

```
<ItemsControl Name="DimsContainer" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DimensionsTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in the Windows Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DimensionsTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Padding="5"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="32"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm trying to implement the ability to drag and drop items within the ItemsControl (i.e. to be able to reorder the integers). Does anyone have a simple example of how to do this? I hooked up the PreviewMouseMove, DragEnter and Drop events. The problem is that I can't figure out how to determine which item is being dragged and where it is dragged to. It seems that the entire ItemsControl gets passed into the events.

Comment: Hi. I see @Golbin's provided link. But the example is about drug and droping between 2 panel. actually I want to reorders in ONE `ItemsControl` just like you. Can you help me please? Can you put your solution code here? Or can you suggest me some guidance please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @king.net do you still need the example related to this issue? here is one related to the listbox - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642622/rearrange-customcontrol-inside-wrappanel-in-wpf-c-sharp. If you need I can try to adapt this for the data template...

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example how I've done it.

***XAML:***

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listview" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Margin="5 2" Width="150" Height="50"
                        FontSize="30" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="PreviewMouseMove" />                        
                    <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="Drop" />                       
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />                        
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

***ViewModel:***

```
 class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new ICommandImplementation();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyData
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<string>(new string[]{
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", 
            "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"
            });
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    private class ICommandImplementation : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void Execute(object parameter) { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Button clicked! " + (parameter ?? "").ToString()); }
    }
}
```

***Events:***

```
 private void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = e.Data.GetData("Source") as string;
        if (source != null)
        {
            int newIndex = listview.Items.IndexOf((sender as Button).Content);
            var list = listview.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;
            list.RemoveAt(list.IndexOf(source));
            list.Insert(newIndex, source);
        }
    }

    private void PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                            {                                    
                                var data = new DataObject();
                                data.SetData("Source", (sender as Button).Content);
                                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender as DependencyObject, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
                                e.Handled = true;
                            }
                        }), null);
                }), CancellationToken.None);
        }           
    }
```

Above example is a little complex cause every item of `list` is a `Button` and on `Button` `click` I also have to do some action. **Your case is relatively easy.**

> Drag & Drop can be confusing for many developers. But below
>   are the some key points how to do it:
>
> 1. Use `PreviewMouseMove` event to actually start a drag and in handler use `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` event to raise `DragDrop` related
>      events and `Cursors`. `sender` argument is the element that has
>      captured the mouse currently in this case the `UIElement` that is
>      being dragged.
> 2. Use `DragEnter` & `DragOver` event if want to change the visual of element over which the `Mouse` is currently dragging. `sender`
>      argument is the element that has currently dragged over / that just
>      ended drag over situation.
> 3. Use `Drop` event to handle the dropped element. `sender` argument is the element on which the Drop happened.
> 4. Use `DataObject` object to pass info between these events. `SetData` method of the class is used to add data in this. This method
>      has two arguments, and they work like `key-value` pair. Once set you
>      can get this data in next called event of `DragDrop` by using
>      `GetData` method by passing the `key` as argument. (i.e.
>      `e.Data.GetData("Source")`)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008970/wpf-scrollviewer-tap-click-tap-and-hold-drag-scroll-how-to-achieve-this/37123349#37123349) is a relative post.

Comment: Thanks for this, Kylo. I was looking for a more simple drag and drop implementation to use and your post gave me all the hints I needed to get it working on my application!