# Rearrange CustomControl inside wrappanel in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, rendering, wrappanel

I am creating a customcontrol dynamically inside a wrappanel. Now i need the reorder the custom controls which are inside the wrappanel. Is it possible to rearrange the custom controls inside the wrappanel using drag and drop?

Here is my XAML code

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="208,40,1,94" Grid.Row="2"
                   Background="White" AllowDrop="True">
            <ScrollViewer  AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="443">
                <StackPanel Width="443" > 


                    <WrapPanel x:Name="pnl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Height="Auto" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" AllowDrop="True" 
                         />

                     </StackPanel> 
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
```

I've tried put the wrap panel inside the list, as it was suggested by the given answer(Ilan's answer), and now my panel is not accessible in the code behind. AM i doing anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Drag Drop in a WrapPanel]

Here I have demonstrated `Buttons`, you can modify it for your needs.

Xaml

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="Pnl" Background="Yellow" Margin="0,0,0,128" Button.DragEnter="Button_DragEnter" Button.MouseRightButtonDown="Button_MouseDown">
    <Button Content="Btn1" AllowDrop="True"/>
    <Button Content="Btn2" AllowDrop="True"/>
    <Button Content="Btn3" AllowDrop="True"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Code

```
Button btn_to_drag;
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    btn_to_drag = (Button)e.Source;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(btn_to_drag, btn_to_drag, DragDropEffects.Move); 
}

private void Button_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)e.Source;
    int where_to_drop = Pnl.Children.IndexOf(btn);
    Pnl.Children.Remove(btn_to_drag);
    Pnl.Children.Insert(where_to_drop, btn_to_drag);
}
```

Another approach using `DataObject` removing the need for `btn_to_drag` declaration.

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, (Button)e.Source );
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)e.Source, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void Button_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn_to_move = (Button) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
            
    int where_to_move = Pnl.Children.IndexOf((UIElement)e.Source);
    int what_to_move = Pnl.Children.IndexOf(btn_to_move);

    Pnl.Children.RemoveAt(what_to_move);
    Pnl.Children.Insert(where_to_move, btn_to_move);
}
```

Comment: After some hour search about this, thanks for this awnser it solved my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your items into the ItemsControl and set the wrappanel to be the ItemsPanel of the control, then just change the order of the controls inside the items control. Here is a simple example(put your control into the InputCollection).

**Update #2 - DragAndDrop**

**Xaml**

```
Window x:Class="WpfCSItemsControlWithWrappanelSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="RootLayout">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBowWithWrapPanel" Background="Green" Margin="5" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="250"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Flip</Button>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind(possible example of drag and drop)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Shape> _observableCollection;
    private int _coordinator = -1;
    private ListBox _dragSource;
    private Shape _dragedData;
    private Shape _targetData;
    private bool _isInDrag;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Shape>
        {
            new Ellipse{Name = "C", Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Tomato},
            new Ellipse{Name = "A", Width = 50, Height = 75, Fill = Brushes.Yellow},
            new Rectangle{Name = "Z", Width = 50, Height = 75, Fill = Brushes.Aqua},
            new Rectangle{Name = "D", Width = 50, Height = 75, Fill = Brushes.Blue},
            new Rectangle{Name = "B", Width = 50, Height = 75, Fill = Brushes.CadetBlue},   
            new Ellipse{Name = "X", Width = 75, Height = 25, Fill = Brushes.Aqua},
        };

        ListBowWithWrapPanel.ItemsSource = _observableCollection;

        Style itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AllowDropProperty, true));
        //we have this to handle a possible dragging element
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBowWithWrapPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown)));
        //we have this to start the dragging process
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(MouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoveHandler)));
        //we have this to stop the where there is no a dragging process
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(LeftButtonUp)));
        //we have this to perform the drop(insert the element into a new position)
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DropEvent, new DragEventHandler(ListBowWithWrapPanel_OnDrop)));
        //we have this to handle the possible target position
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DragOverEvent, new DragEventHandler(OnDragOver)));
        ListBowWithWrapPanel.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// sort when button click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = _observableCollection.ToList();
        _observableCollection.Clear();

        _coordinator *= -1;

        list.Sort((shape, shape1) =>
        {
            var name1 = shape.Name;
            var name2 = shape1.Name;

            return string.Compare(name1, name2, StringComparison.Ordinal) * _coordinator;
        });

        list.ForEach(shape =>
        {
            _observableCollection.Add(shape);
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// we have this to handle a possible dragging element
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ListBowWithWrapPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem == null) return;
        _dragSource = listBoxItem.FindParent<ListBox>();
        _dragedData = listBoxItem.DataContext as Shape;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// we have this to start the dragging process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void MouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragedData != null && _isInDrag == false)
        {
            _isInDrag = true;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragSource, _dragedData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// we have this to handle the possible target position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="dragEventArgs"></param>
    private void OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        var targetPlaceHolder = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (targetPlaceHolder == null) return;
        _targetData = targetPlaceHolder.DataContext as Shape;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// we have this to stop where there is no a dragging process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void LeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ResumeDragging();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// we have this to perform the drop(insert the element into a new position)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ListBowWithWrapPanel_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Equals(_dragedData, _targetData)) return;
        var targetPlaceHolder = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (targetPlaceHolder == null) return;

        var removedIdx = _observableCollection.IndexOf(_dragedData);
        var targetIdx = _observableCollection.IndexOf(_targetData);

        if (removedIdx < targetIdx)
        {
            _observableCollection.Insert(targetIdx + 1, _dragedData);
            _observableCollection.RemoveAt(removedIdx);
        }
        else
        {
            int remIdx = removedIdx + 1;
            if (_observableCollection.Count + 1 > remIdx)
            {
                _observableCollection.Insert(targetIdx, _dragedData);
                _observableCollection.RemoveAt(remIdx);
            }
        }

        ResumeDragging();

    }

    private void ResumeDragging()
    {
        _isInDrag = false;
        _dragedData = null;
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I kept my wrap panel inside the item control as you said.But now that panel was not accessible in the code behind :( why its so?

Comment: @dahsra what for you need it to be accessible? Please keep in your mind that you add items to ItemsControl, and then they are enter to the wrappanel.

Comment: Now i am creating a usercontrol dynamically inside that wrap panel in code behind,now you need me to create that controls inside the Itemscontrol uh??

Comment: @dahsra common, you just create the control, and put that into the ListBox items source. This is exactly the same.

Comment: have updated my question can you please tell whether am doing it correwcvtly..?

Comment: @dahsra dear dahsra I've edited your query a little bit, but I can't understand what is the problem? As I've mentioned before, you don't need the wrappanel to be accessible, you just insert items(controls) into the ItemsSource collection of the ListBox. I will update my answer in a few moments.

Comment: Thanks it works for me,but how to drag drop items indise the listbox now..?

Comment: @dahsra see the updates with a possible drag and drop example.